# Windows 8.1 Clean Install vs Windows Update Benefits?

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, windows-installation

Is there any benefit to doing a clean install of Windows 8.1 versus doing the platform upgrade from windows update, such as better performance, etc?

Comment: Windows 8.1 is designed to be installed like a Service Pack.  Everything that needs to be done will be done during the upgrade process.

Comment: no 8.1 was developed as a new Windows, but released as free upgrade because of the Windows 8 marketshare disaster. A SP never removes functions like 8.1 does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8.1 is often referred to as windows 8 service pack 1. The reason for this being it is more or less a upgrade to the OS, with the option of doing a clean install of the OS with the upgrade. To surmise, there is no real benefit unless you're computer is already loaded down with junk and you want to clean that off at the same time.